# I want to know how capture RAW data packets in a Queue using Iptables or Nftables

Tags: python-2.7, iptables, packet, scapy, netfilter

My doubt is I want to captire raw data packets, so that I can use them to built firewall.
The following script prints a short description of each packet before accepting it.
    from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue

```
def print_and_accept(pkt):
    print pkt
    pkt.accept()

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, print_and_accept)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
```

To send packets destined for your LAN to the script, type something like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

Comment: What is your question? How is that related to Scapy?

Comment: I am looking for any methods to drop packets with/without using scapy. Scapy helps in capturing packtes, but I do not know how to drop.

Comment: No, Scapy (here) does not capture packets, it might be used to dissect them, and that's all. Netfilter's NFQUEUE target "captures" the packets. Have you tried `pkt.drop()` instead of `.accept()`?

Comment: NFQUEUE captures Layer 3 information, I want to drop packets based on L2 information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, by raw packet you mean layer 2. Iptables works at layer 3, you need to use ebtables instead.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre,  I did checked eatables, but still did not get exactly what I need, as its under construction.

Comment: I think sadly you have no option left but wait…